# MySQL Update error

Tags: mysql, syntax

```
UPDATE `Starcraft2uvsu` 
SET IF(`Starcraft2uvsu`.username =  'wasd',  'report1',  'report2' ) =  'Win' 
FROM `Starcraft2uvsu` 
WHERE `Starcraft2uvsu`.username =  'wasd'
```

The error phpmyadmin is spitting out is...

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'If(Starcraft2uvsu.username = wasd, 'report1', 'report2') = 'Win' FROM Starcraft2' at line 1
```

Is it even possible to set a column name through a if statement? I guess that's the killer.

The magically query was a combination of answers and comments..

```
UPDATE Starcraft2uvsu 
SET report1 = CASE WHEN Starcraft2uvsu.username = 'wasd' THEN 'win' ELSE report1 END,
    report2 = CASE WHEN Starcraft2uvsu.username <> 'wasd' THEN 'win' ELSE report2 END
WHERE Starcraft2uvsu.username = 'wasd' OR Starcraft2uvsu.username2 = 'wasd'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.  You do it like:

```
set report1 = if (username = 'wasd', 'Win', report1),
    report2 = if (username = 'wasd', report2, 'Win')
```

Comment: UPDATE  `Starcraft2uvsu` SET report1 = IF( username =  'wasd',  'Win',  'report2' ) ,
report2 = IF( username =  'wasd', report2,  'Win' ) FROM  `Starcraft2uvsu` WHERE username =  'wasd'

gives


#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `Starcraft2uvsu` 
WHERE username = 'wasd'' at line 3 

I hate SQL :P

Comment: I am also a little confused by your where clause; you want to update different columns based on username, but you select a particular username?

Comment: I could have sworn I saw UPDATE SET FROM in someone elses. But right you are sir, without the FROM clause the query worked.

Comment: The where wasn't complete it is now, see my question I'll edit soon.

Comment: Sorry I misread your comment, The Where clause was generated from a php script, and sent to be queried, but I wanted to keep it to one query rather than having 2 queries or 3, as it will be a often run one. Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to update from your syntax.  You want to use a CASE statement similar to  this:

```
UPDATE Starcraft2uvsu 
SET report1 = CASE WHEN Starcraft2uvsu.username = 'wasd' THEN 'win' ELSE report1 END,
    report2 = CASE WHEN IFNULL(Starcraft2uvsu.username,'') <> 'wasd' THEN 'win' ELSE report2 END
FROM Starcraft2uvsu 
WHERE Starcraft2uvsu.username = 'wasd'
```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't select both of your answers, I marked you up.

Comment: note that by using `<>` instead of `Starcraft2uvsu.username = 'wasd' THEN report2 ELSE 'win'`, you make a null username not change either field.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't select the left-hand-side of an assignment like this in SQL (or in most languages). You're going to need an `IF` statement that executes an `UPDATE` on `report1` in one branch, and an `UPDATE` on `report2` in the other. You could also move that logic up into your business logic layer and have it construct the right `UPDATE` statement. My preference would be to keep this logic out of the database, personally.

Comment: Oops, I'm thinking of stored procedure syntax really... which also works. But I think what you're trying to do can't really be done, or as ysth says, can be done only with a funny trick.

Comment: Yea, I wanted to keep it on the database if I could

Answer (score 0):

What you have is also equivalent to this:

```
UPDATE Starcraft2uvsu 
SET report1 = 'win'
WHERE Starcraft2uvsu.username = 'wasd' ;

UPDATE Starcraft2uvsu 
SET report2 =  'win' 
WHERE Starcraft2uvsu.username <> 'wasd'
  AND Starcraft2uvsu.username2 = 'wasd' ;
```